# Shell: how write multiline text file without escaping special symbols?

Tags: bash, shell

I know the question sounds to be discussed thousands times before. But somehow I can't find good solution.

Problem: I need to write multiline text from shell. The text might contain special chars sequences (starting from $) and I don't want to escape them. How to do this?

Currently I'm using cat:

```
cat <<TAGTEXTFILE > sometext.txt
Here is some text in which I don't want to escape sequences like: $().
I just want to see this text in this script exactly as 
it will look in resulting sometext.txt file.
TAGTEXTFILE
```

But with cat I have to escape this: $(). How to write multiline text without escaping special characters? Please don't offer to use Python, I need shell solution (bash or dash).

Comment: What is your system ? i cannot reproduce your issue on mines (Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 5). Copy/paste your code worked like a charm...

Comment: @user2196728 it works, but it wouldn't work if it had $PWD in it, for example. that's the point

Comment: Do you want `$PWD` to be expanded (like `/home/vladimir/foo/`) or not?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. My sample wasn't from real life, I just changed it. So '$()' appears in script but it doesn't in resulting text file. I understand why, I just don't need this functionality. In fact I do not want anything to be expanded, nor $PWD neither $(...) commands and still need to have convenient way to write multiline text.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
cat <<"TAGTEXTFILE" > sometext.txt
... some text ...
TAGTEXTFILE
```

Comment: Wow! What a trick! How do you learn such things? Is it somewhere in man?

Comment: it is in `info bash`. But generally when I want to know how to do something in bash I use Google, because the documentation is hard to navigate.

Comment: See the section of the `man` page under "Here documents". The relevant sentence is "If any characters in _word_ are quoted, [...] the lines in the here-document are not expanded".

Comment: This is some kind of black magic.